# Display partial view in modal not pulling the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am attempting to display a modal with data rendered in a partial view when the user hovers over a persons name in the view. I can get the modal to display, but there is no data and since the name to be displayed in the view is generated by a linq statement, the divs all have the same class designation. This causes all the names on the page to display a model when one is hovered over. I am not sure how to get past these issues.

Here is what I have so far...

**JQuery to create and populate the modal**

```
$(document).ready(function (data) {
    $('accountNumber').hover(function () {
        var id = $(this).data("personID")
        $(".modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: parent },
            width: 300,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Accounts Information',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("_AccountNumberModal", "ICMS", ' + id + ')');
            },
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Controller Action for the partial view**

```
public ActionResult _AccountNumberModal(SearchViewModel viewModel, string id)
        {
            tblPeople people = db.tblPeoples.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PeopleCounterID.ToString() == id);
            {
                viewModel.FirstName = people.FirstName;
                viewModel.LastName = people.LastName;
                viewModel.AccountNumber = people.AccountNumber;
                viewModel.AccountNumber2 = people.AccountNumber2;
                viewModel.AccountNumber3 = people.AccountNumber3;
                viewModel.AccountNumber4 = people.AccountNumber4;
                viewModel.AccountClosed = people.AccountClosed;
                viewModel.AccountClosed2 = people.AccountClosed2;
                viewModel.AccountClosed3 = people.AccountClosed3;
                viewModel.AccountClosed4 = people.AccountClosed4;
                viewModel.AccountClosedDate1 = people.AccountClosedDate1;
                viewModel.AccountClosedDate2 = people.AccountClosedDate2;
                viewModel.AccountClosedDate3 = people.AccountClosedDate3;
                viewModel.AccountClosedDate4 = people.AccountClosedDate4;
                viewModel.TypeofAccount1 = people.TypeofAccount1;
                viewModel.TypeofAccount2 = people.TypeofAccount2;
                viewModel.TypeofAccount3 = people.TypeofAccount3;
                viewModel.TypeofAccount4 = people.TypeofAccount4;
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

**Partial view**

```
@model FHN.EIR.Web.Models.SearchViewModel

<section id="accountNumbers" class="sectionHeadingBold">Account Information</section>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.AccountNumber))
{
    <dl class="inline dl-rows">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TypeofAccount1)
        </dt>
        <dd class="width-275px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TypeofAccount1)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosed)
        </dt>
        <dd class="width-dateField">
            @if (Model.AccountClosed)
                {
                @Html.DisplayName("Closed")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DisplayName("Open")
            }
        </dd>
        @if (Model.AccountClosed)
        {
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate1)
            </dt>
                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate1)
                </dd>
        }
    </dl>
        <br />
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.AccountNumber2))
    {
        <dl class="inline dl-rows">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountNumber2)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber2)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TypeofAccount2)
            </dt>
            <dd class="width-250px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TypeofAccount2)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosed2)
            </dt>
            <dd class="width-dateField">
                @if (Model.AccountClosed2)
                    {
                    @Html.DisplayName("Closed")
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayName("Open")
                }
            </dd>
            @if (Model.AccountClosed2)
            {
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate2)
                </dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate2)
                    </dd>
            }
        </dl>
            <br />
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.AccountNumber3))
    {
        <dl class="inline dl-rows">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountNumber3)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber3)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TypeofAccount3)
            </dt>
            <dd class="width-250px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TypeofAccount3)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosed3)
            </dt>
            <dd class="width-dateField">
                @if (Model.AccountClosed3)
                    {
                    @Html.DisplayName("Closed")
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayName("Open")
                }
            </dd>
            @if (Model.AccountClosed3)
            {
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate3)
                </dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate3)
                    </dd>
            }
        </dl>
            <br />
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.AccountNumber4))
    {
        <dl class="inline dl-rows">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountNumber4)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountNumber4)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TypeofAccount4)
            </dt>
            <dd class="width-250px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TypeofAccount4)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosed4)
            </dt>
            <dd class="width-dateField">
                @if (Model.AccountClosed4)
                    {
                    @Html.DisplayName("Closed")
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayName("Open")
                }

            </dd>
            @if (Model.AccountClosed4)
            {
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate4)
                </dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountClosedDate4)
                    </dd>
            }
        </dl>
    }
}
else
{
    <dl class="inline dl-rows">
        <dt>
            <span class="mar-l-15px inline-messages">There are no accounts associated with this person</span>
        </dt>
    </dl>
}
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the data to populate. Just not sure how to make it so that only the name hovered over opens a related modal versus having all names open modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial views don't utilize actions to load. They have to be passed a model directly.

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial", myPartialModel)
```

If you don't pass a model, the main views model is passed implicitly.

If you need to utilize an action to render a partial view, then you're talking about child actions. The syntax for that is:

```
@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

However, there's a few things to note. The action you use for this should return `PartialView` rather than `View`. A partial view is only a partial view when it's used as a partial view. If you return `View`, your partial will behave as a standard view would and utilize a layout. Next, since your action is now returning a partial view, it's very unlikely you would ever want to serve it directly. To not expose it the main routing infrastructure (such that you can access via a URL), you should decorate it with `[ChildActionOnly]`.

Finally, bear in mind that rendering a child action requires a non-trivial amount of overhead. It basically goes through the standard routing infrastructure just like a normal action, before being rendered to the page. Using a few on a page is no big deal, but if you're talking about 100s or something, it's going to kill performance significantly. Because of this, it's not recommended to use child actions unless there's actually a *reason*, like you need to issue a query to the database to fetch something completely unrelated to the view. A good example would be something like a recent posts widget on a blog. The main view might be display a single blog post, and then you can utilize a child action to query the recent posts to fill that widget area. However, if all you're going to do is return static data, it's a waste, and a partial is much better suited.

Even then, pay attention that "unrelated" bit above. In the blog example, it would make no sense for the main action being rendered (displaying a single blog post) to also have to fetch a collection of recent posts to fill some widget, probably in the layout. That's why it makes sense to use a child action. But, in your example here, the entire point of your action is to display information about people, so utilizing a child action to actually fetch the information for those people one by one, makes no sense. Instead, you should query all this information and return it as part of one model to your view.